# listview setonitemclicklistener doesn't work?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

CustomAdapter.class

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] titleArray;
    String[] descriptionArrayl;
    public CustomAdapter(Context c,String[] memeTitles,int[] imgs,String[] descriptionArrayl) {
super(c,R.layout.row,R.id.etTitle,memeTitles);
        this.context=c;
        this.images = imgs;
        this.titleArray = memeTitles;
        this.descriptionArrayl=descriptionArrayl;
    }
    //Sub class of CustomAdapter
    class MyViewHolder{
        ImageView myImage;
        TextView myTitle;
        TextView myDescription;
        MyViewHolder(View v){

            myImage= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
            myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.etDescriptions);
        }
    }

    //Get View Method of CustomAdapter class
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row=convertView;
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder =null;
        if (row==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(row);
            Log.d("List View","Creating New Row");
            row.setTag(myViewHolder);
        }else {
            myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
            Log.d("List View","Recycling Stuff");

        }
        myViewHolder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        myViewHolder.myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
        myViewHolder.myDescription.setText(descriptionArrayl[position]);


        return row;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
package com.faisal.listviewtask;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] memeTitles;
    String[] memeDescriptions;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    int[] image = {R.drawable.meme1, R.drawable.meme2,
            R.drawable.meme3, R.drawable.meme4,
            R.drawable.meme5, R.drawable.meme6,
            R.drawable.meme7, R.drawable.meme8,
            R.drawable.meme9, R.drawable.meme10,
            R.drawable.meme1, R.drawable.meme2,
            R.drawable.meme3, R.drawable.meme4,
            R.drawable.meme5, R.drawable.meme6,
            R.drawable.meme7, R.drawable.meme8,
            R.drawable.meme9, R.drawable.meme10};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


        Resources res = getResources();
        memeTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        memeDescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, memeTitles, image, memeDescriptions);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you clicked" + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("onitemclick Listener","called");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:context="com.faisal.listviewtask.MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

row layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/etTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/etDescriptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is all my code given. I added all tags like `android:focusable="false"`, `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in row of list view and also I added `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in root layout of listview and `listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);` in code before the `listView.setOnItemClickListener` but after this onitem click listener does not work and no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you your all code is correct and also no Exception is remain in your code But  your ListView On ItemClickListener  is not working then you need to use
Restart/invalidate caches option available in Android studio then Run the Listview Project then OnItemClick Listener work correctly.
Click on the File Option on top left corner of the android studio the select the invalidate caches/restart option .

Answer (score 0):

```
        add this in Activity [updated]

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, memeTitles, image, memeDescriptions,new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
        int i=(Integer)view.getTag();
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you clicked" + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("onitemclick Listener","called");
                    }


                });
                listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        And add id as rootLayout in row xml

        public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            Context context;
            int[] images;
            String[] titleArray;
            String[] descriptionArrayl;
    OnClickListener onClickListener;
            public CustomAdapter(Context c,String[] memeTitles,int[] imgs,String[] descriptionArrayl,OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        super(c,R.layout.row,R.id.etTitle,memeTitles);
                this.context=c;
                this.images = imgs;
                this.titleArray = memeTitles;
                this.descriptionArrayl=descriptionArrayl;
                this.onClickListener=onClickListener;
            }
            //Sub class of CustomAdapter
            class MyViewHolder{
                ImageView myImage;
                TextView myTitle;
                TextView myDescription;
                RelativeLayout rootLayout;
                MyViewHolder(View v){
        rootLayout=(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
                    myImage= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
                    myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.etDescriptions);
                }
            }

            //Get View Method of CustomAdapter class
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                View row=convertView;
                MyViewHolder myViewHolder =null;
                if (row==null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                    myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(row);
                    Log.d("List View","Creating New Row");
                    row.setTag(myViewHolder);
                }else {
                    myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
                    Log.d("List View","Recycling Stuff");

                }
                myViewHolder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
                myViewHolder.myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
                myViewHolder.myDescription.setText(descriptionArrayl[position]);
        rootLayout.setTag(position);
        rootLayout.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

                return row;
            }
        }


row layout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/etTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/etDescriptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this.onClickListener=onClickListener;
how to add this one show error
,view.OnClickListener onClickListener 
in paramerter are used with out view show red line

Comment: @FaisalShabbir just declare class variable onClickListener in Adapter

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.faisal.listviewtask.CustomAdapter$MyViewHolder
                      at com.faisal.listviewtask.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:57)
now this exception occure after adding the onclicklistener of rootlayout
on this line :   myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();

Comment: @FaisalShabbir you are setting id as rootLayout to  main layout . main layout has already set tag as ViewHolder

Comment: @FaisalShabbir For this add another RelativeLayout inside main layout and give id as rootLayout it will works

Comment: inside Relativelayout add another layout out and inside this layout add list view ?? are you mean

Comment: sir where add Relativelayout in main.xml or row.xml file ??

Comment: @FaisalShabbir  i am updated row.xml  in answer please check

Comment: sir not work just on time work for on row then no response

Comment: Yes sir Work now

Comment: Extremely Thanks for giving his priceless time for my help
Thanks a lot God Bless You (y)

Comment: @FaisalShabbir Welcome,  it's my pleasure

Comment: sir one question more in this case on cliklistener of relativelayout work but sir any solution in which onItemclicklistener of listview work??

Comment: @FaisalShabbir  Please ask

Comment: in this case on cliklistener of relativelayout work but sir any solution in which onItemclicklistener of listview work??

Comment: @FaisalShabbir actually onItemclicklistener  is work but in your case it is not working that's given this answer .You can try other time is will be work

Comment: Ok sir Bundle of Thanks again sir <3